# Python - Erroneous result for two different matrixes in nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, nested

I have a problem with matrix operations in nested loop. I looked on stackoverflow before posting this question, all the subjects I found treated only one matrix.

My loop tries to computes two matrixes, giving 2 for each element in the first one and 1 in the second one. However the same matrix is given as an output.

I tried to duplicate the loops with one matrix in each, but the same erroneous result was given.

Thank you for your help!

```
dummy_matrix = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(2)]
other_matrix = dummy_matrix
  for x in range(2):
   for i in range(2):
    dummy_matrix[x][i] = 2
    other_matrix[x][i] = 1
print 'dummy_matrix =',dummy_matrix
print 'other_matrix =',other_matrix
The answer is
dummy_matrix = [[1, 1], [1, 1]] # expected result : [[2, 2], [2, 2]]
other_matrix = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: Please do not add 'SOLVED' to your question. We already know you got an answer that helped you, that's what the [green check mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) in the left margin indicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
other_matrix = dummy_matrix
```

you're asking Python to bind the name `other_matrix` to the *same object* that `dummy_matrix` is bound to. So

```
dummy_matrix[x][i] = 2
other_matrix[x][i] = 1   # overwrites the previous value
```

Just do

```
other_matrix = [[0 for x in range(2)] for x in range(2)]
```

instead.

Comment: In what cases does this `binding` happens? Because when I do that for integers, `>>> y = 1
>>> x = y
>>> x+=1
>>> x
2
>>> y
1
>>> ` it is not so. Could you point me to some official resource.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim!! This works perfectly now, you saved my week-end!

Comment: @tMJ: Yes, it is so. But you're doing different things in your example (rebinding the name to a new object), whereas the OP's code is modifying the object in-place. `x += 1` means "take the value of `x`, add 1 to it, then bind `x` to the result". `x[0] = 2` means "change the first element of `x` to `2`".

Comment: Appreciate the help @TimPietzcker, but I am getting nowhere near understanding this. Could you point me to some resource where I can read about this, or tell me what's it called so I can look for it myself.

Comment: @tMJ: Sure: Net Batchelder has written a great blog post about this: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line

```
other_matrix = dummy_matrix
```

You are not creating a copy of `dummy_matrix` with this line, but you are making `other_matrix` also to point to the same list which `dummy_matrix` is also pointing to. To actually create a copy, you can use slicing notation like this

```
other_matrix = dummy_matrix[:]
```